# Node.js return value is undefined

Tags: node.js, ecmascript-6

`token` in the below snippet is always `undefined`. Can someone help me out figuring what's wrong here?

```
[err, token] = await to(comparePassHash(body.password, user.password));`

comparePassHash = async (pass, hash) => {
    bcrypt.compare(pass, hash, (err, token) => {
        if (err) TE(err);
        console.log('test');
        return token;
    });
};


to = (promise) => {
    return promise
    .then(data => {
        return [null, data];
    }).catch(err =>
        [pe(err)]
    );
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's `undefined` because that's what `comparePassHash` resolves.

`async` keyword won't work as you expect in that case. You're returning `token` inside `.compare` function, not inside `comparePassHash`. You have to wrap `bcrypt.compare` with a `Promise`.

```
const comparePassHash = (pass, hash) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        bcrypt.compare(pass, hash, (err, token) => {
            if (err) 
                return reject(err);
            console.log('test');
            return resolve(token);
        });
    });
};
```

---

Take your function:

```
comparePassHash = async (pass, hash) => {
    bcrypt.compare(pass, hash, (err, token) => {
        if (err) TE(err);
        console.log('test');
        return token;
    });

   // implicit return: undefined
};
```

Without an `await` it will execute `bcrypt.compare`, it will not wait until it finishes, since it's not a promise, and it will exit the function, returning `undefined` since you're missing a `return` statement.

Another way is to use `Util.promisify`

```
const { promisify } = require('util');
const comparePassHash= promisify(bcrypt.compare);

// This must be inside an async function
[err, token] = await to(comparePassHash(body.password, user.password));
```

Comment: thanks for the support! can you suggest on what topics i need study to gain more knowledge regarding these?

Comment: You're welcome! You should probably read more about callback and promises, to understand the differences. Once you fully understand them, read again about async/await